# Как полностью удалить visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio

Программа лагает при запуске, и вешает систему. Появилась сия радость после установки web компонента для работы с ASP.NET. Пробовал через программы и компоненты удалять все что устанавливается вместе со студией, вплоть до дотнет4, потом заново запускать установку. Инсталляция вылетал с ошибкой на первом же этапе. Подскажите, что можно сделать.
вижак professional лицензионный, качал с DreamSpark.

Comment: попробуй дедовский способ, win+r -> regedit -> F3  ищи и удаляй что хочешь =)

Comment: Gorets, твой дед был спартанцем? как я удалю VS удаляя ключи реестра?!?!